# Running code on URL change (custom scheme) without launching new activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview

I have set up a custom URL scheme for my app using intent filters. When the URL changes in my WebView to my custom scheme (mockup://pagechange), the intent filter correctly filters the intent to my app, launching a new instance of my activity. However, what I actually want to happen is for the intent filter to run a piece of code inside the existing activity rather than launching a new activity. Is this possible, and if so, how do I set this up? If not, any other ideas on how to accomplish the task of running code when the URL in my WebView changes to anything beginning with 'mockup'?

I have tried using other actions in the intent filter, but the ones I've tried (RUN and ATTACH_DATA) result in the "Web page not available" page being displayed in my WebView when the url changes.  Also, all of the intent filter / custom scheme questions I've found here deal with figuring out how to start a new activity with a url with a custom scheme - makes it hard to search for the opposite.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up moving away from the intent filter pattern - I had already set up a WebViewClient for my WebView to handle loading external links in my WebView, so I just set a flag in there to run my code if the URL that is being loaded contains the custom scheme I'm looking for:

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.app_container);
// [other setup]
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            if(!url.contains("mockup://"))
                view.loadUrl(url);
            else {
                // run "mockup"-specific code
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

First, add `android:launchMode="singleTop"` your activity declaration in the manifest. In your intent use the flags `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. You'll get the intent in the onNewIntent() callback.

Remember that the intent delivered in onNewIntent() is not the same as returned in getIntent(). If you make use of getIntent() in other parts of your code, use setIntent on the intent from onNewIntent().

Comment: The launchMode option certainly seems like what I want to do (not launch a new instance of the Activity, but just call a method - onNewIntent() in this case).  But where would I set the flags?  I'm not explicitly creating a new activity, I am trying to catch the action of a URL change on my WebView to a custom scheme - never actually setting up an Intent object in code.

Comment: You're right of course. Just create a new Activity whose sole purpose is to start other activities. So, in the new Activity, don't show any UI, just call startActivity after processing the intent and forward it to your single top activity.